# How to run a function both in a ray-parallel & without using ray modes?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, ray

After `sudo pip3 install ray`

I have created a function **`foo()`**, defined within a ray decorator :

```
import ray
ray.init()

@ray.remote
def foo(x):
    print(x)
```

I want to be able to use the `foo` both in a parallel and in a regular mode (ignoring the decorator).

If I want to use `foo` without a `.remote( blabla_variable )` it will return me an error.

Please advise how to *"ignore"* the decorator when I don't need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One workaround is to do the following

```
import ray
ray.init()

def local_foo(x):
    print(x)

remote_foo = ray.remote(local_foo)

# Call foo locally.
local_foo('arg')

# Call foo remotely.
remote_foo.remote('arg')
```

Comment: how to argument (like object_store_memory) to this ?