# what is the python ray syntax to use an imported function as a ray remote function with decorator arg such as num_cpus

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, ray

I am trying to use an imported function as a ray remote function, however the usual syntax to declare a remote function doesn't seem to work. There are several other related questions on stackoverflow that don't fully answer my question, see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65493701/decorator-function-to-wrap-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308409/how-to-run-a-function-both-in-a-ray-parallel-without-using-ray-modes). Link 1 'seems' to solve the issue but seems very clunky and does't look like the way I would expect the ray developers intend it to be used. Ref 2 solves a similar issue 'except' if you need to give arguments to the decorated function (as i do in my case) then it returns the following error:

```
AssertionError: The @ray.remote decorator must be applied either with no arguments and no parentheses, for example '@ray.remote', or it must be applied using some of the arguments 'num_returns', 'num_cpus', 'num_gpus', 'memory', 'object_store_memory', 'resources', 'max_calls', or 'max_restarts', like '@ray.remote(num_returns=2, resources={"CustomResource": 1})'.
```

Here is an example of full working code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import ray 
from ray.cluster_utils import Cluster 

config = {
    "cluster_cpus":3,
    "n_cores":1
}


df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['a'] = [1,2,3]
df1['b'] = [4,5,6]


try:

    # init ray 
    # Start a head node for the cluster
    if not ray.is_initialized():
        master_cluster = Cluster(
            initialize_head=True,
            head_node_args={"num_cpus":config["cluster_cpus"]}
            )

        # start ray (after initializing cluster)
        try:
            ray.init(address=master_cluster.address, include_dashboard=False, log_to_driver=True)
        except TypeError:
            ray.init(address=master_cluster.address, include_webui=False)

        df_id = df1

        @ray.remote(num_cpus=config["n_cores"])
        def sp_workflow(df, sp):

            sp["output"] = df.sum(axis=1).values * sp["input"]

            return sp        
  

        model_pool = [{"input":1},{"input":2},{"input":3}]
        outputs = []
        result_ids = [sp_workflow.remote(df=df_id, sp=sp) for sp in model_pool]
        
        # Loop over the pending results and process completed jobs
        while len(result_ids):
            done_id, result_ids = ray.wait(result_ids)
            sp = ray.get(done_id[0])   
            outputs.append(sp)       

        print(outputs)     

except Exception as e:
    raise e

finally:
    if ray.is_initialized():
        ray.shutdown()
```

However, in my case 'sp_workflow' is a function stored in another script and so cannot have the @ray.remote(num_cpus=config["n_cores") decorator applied to it. If I need to specify the number of cores to give an imported function that I wish to use remotely then its not clear in the ray docs how to do this? - Unless I missed something?

I tried replacing the sp_workflow definition with the imported version and the remote call with the following line but it gives the error mentioned earlier:

```
from other_library import sp_workflow
result_ids = [ray.remote(sp_workflow(df=df_id, sp=sp), num_cpus=config["n_cores"] ) for sp in model_pool]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Ray Nishihara answer mentioned in your post, I propose you not to miss the first step of converting your function to remote version `remote_foo = ray.remote(local_foo)`, where you may pass num_cpus argument.

So in your case it should be like this:

```
from other_library import sp_workflow
sp_workflow_rm = ray.remote(sp_workflow, config["n_cores"])
result_ids = [ray.remote(sp_workflow_rm(df=df_id, sp=sp)) for sp in model_pool]
```

I have not tested it, hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Many thanks for looking at this, however this answer returns the 'AssertionError' mentioned at the top of my post, the 'ray.remote(sp_workflow, config["n_cores"])' line doesn't execute and throws the error, I have also tried it as 'ray.remote(sp_workflow, num_cpus=config["n_cores"])', but it throws the same error.